# How can I install from a 9.04 live USB/DVD?

Tags: installation, boot, grub2, live-usb, 9.04

I have a 9.04 (Jaunty) ISO burned to a USB stick; it appears to be a "live DVD". When I boot from it, I get a GRUB menu listing:

- `Ubuntu, with Linux 2.6.35-generic` *(This matches the system currently installed on the HDD?)*
- `Ubuntu, with Linux 2.6.35-generic (recovery mode)`
- `Memory test`
- `Ubuntu 9.04, kernel 2.6.28-11-generic (on /dev/sda1)`
- `Ubuntu 9.04, kernel 2.6.28-11-generic (recovery mode) (on /dev/sda1)`
- `Ubuntu 9.04, memtest86+ (on /dev/sda1)`

When I select `Ubuntu 9.04, kernel 2.6.28-11-generic (on /dev/sda1)`, I arrive at the desktop of a 9.04 system. I want to wipe the HDD clean and install 9.04. (Upgrading to something newer is not an option; this version is required by a legacy application.)

**How can I install from this live USB image?**

I vaguely remember some incantation that I should be able to use in the booted system, but my google-fu is broken at the moment.

I'm comfortable with low-level commands, so if you want to recommend a more hard-core strategy, I'm willing to roll with it without requiring a ton of detail...

Comment: Why 9.04? and not 10.04 LTS?

Comment: @uri re-read the question - this legacy application requires it.

Comment: @UriHerrera: I'd prefer to be on 10.04, but at the moment that's not a possibility.

Comment: You should be aware that continuing to run Ubuntu 9.04 puts you (and your clients/customers, if applicable) at risk, since one of the things that it means for an Ubuntu release to be end-of-life (unsupported) is that security updates are no longer provided for security vulnerabilities as they are discovered (and there are plenty such vulnerabilities, for any old general-purpose OS including Ubuntu). I recommend that you consider alternatives for running your legacy application (or even consider migrating away from the legacy application, if necessary).

Comment: You may want to post another question here on AskUbuntu, asking for ideas about running your application on a supported operating system.

Comment: @EliahKagan: Thanks for the warning. I'm aware of the risks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fact that you're getting a GRUB menu with what's currently installed on your HDD suggests that you're not booting from the USB, but from the hard drive instead. You need to go into BIOS setup and make sure the USB stick comes first in the list of boot devices.

If you still see the same GRUB menu after confirming the the USB is first in the list - it suggests that the USB drive is not bootable so BIOS skips it and goes to the next one in the list. You may need to re-create it.

Comment: But 9.04 comes up in the GRUB list?

Comment: Ah, you must be right. GRUB is reporting 1.98, which comes with 10.10, so the USB must not be bootable. (BIOS is set properly.) I used `usb-creator-gtk` from 10.04 to create the USB stick, what would cause it to not boot properly?

Comment: *head slap* That's what I get for trying to squeeze this in at the deadline... the ISO is too big to fit on the disk. Would be nice if usb creator gave an error message instead of just telling me it was finished. Thanks @Sergey, for pointing me in the right direction!